# How to delete event handler automatically in a MFC CDialog class?

Tags: mfc

I am using Visual C++ 2010 & MFC to write a small dialog-based application.

I click a control (such as a "static text" control) in the dialog，and the corresponding class creates a function and variable automatically.

Now I find the event handler is useless. How can I delete the event handler automatically?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a way to delete them automatically - I've always just done it by hand.

Comment: @MarkRansom It can be done. Atleast, using the functionality that is available. Please see my answer. It is not fully automatic though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can right click it in one of the propert windows and choose delete event handler. But what it will do is comment out the code.

It can also be done from the [ClassWizard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa293836(v=vs.60).aspx). Quote:

> With **ClassView** and **WizardBar**, deleting a message-handling function is the same as deleting any other member function. **ClassView** and **WizardBar**:
>
> - delete the function *declaration*
> - removes any associated *map entry* from the `MSG`, `MESSAGE` or `DISPATCH` map
> - and comment out the *function body*, or definition, so that you can easily delete it if you wish.

This includes variables. There is more information about other ways [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa293832(v=vs.60).aspx)

---

## Class Wizard

- Right-click the dialog resource and choose **Class Wizard**

[image: Class Wizard]

- Select the event handler you want to delete and then choose **Delete Handler**

[image: Delete Handler]

---

## Class View

- Select the class first so that it has focus:

[image: Select class in Class View]

- Click the *lightening bolt* on the **Properties** pane and then *expand* the control to see the events:

[image: Properties]

- Click on the *drop arrow* and select **Delete**:

[image: Delete]

Hopefully this are enough examples to show you how you can delete functions. Please let me know if you want me to provide you with more information.

Comment: @zet Please see updated answer. Please remember to upvote it too if you have found it useful and informative. Thanks. :)